# Create SMO Server object in MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, smo

I'm trying to create a SMO Server object in MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio and keep getting errors on this line:

```
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(new SqlConnection(connectionString)));
```

I've even just tried:

```
Server server = new Server();
```

This is the error that is thrown:

```
Could not load type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlContext' from assembly 'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlContext' from assembly 'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager..ctor (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnectionObject) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection..ctor (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x003bc] in Program.cs:107
```

Anyone have any ideas, or need anymore info?  The same code works fine in BIDS (Visual Studio 2008).

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:

[SMO Tutorial from Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17169/Copy-Data-from-a-DataTable-to-a-SQLServer-Database)

Comment: Looking through the Mono API reference, it doesn't seem like there is any reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlContext (or anything Microsoft.SqlServer) in the System.Data namespace. Are you sure this functionality is available on Mono? There is a separate Microsoft.SqlServer namespace but it doesn't have any reference to a Server.SqlContext sub-namespace.

Comment: @RonBeyer - Good question.  I hadn't look at it, but looking at this link it appears to be?  http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=N%3aMicrosoft.SqlServer.Server

Comment: Yes, thats there, but seems to be missing the SqlContext object in that namespace, to it seems to be missing from the implementation.

Comment: @RonBeyer - Ah, yep, looks like that's missing.  Interesting.

Comment: Here's a bug in Xamarin's bug tracker: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=29221

Comment: @EdAvis - thanks for attaching the link here. That's the bug I submitted after I posted the question here :)